# Go to the previous wallet address

Tags: bitcoin-core

￼The computer reinstalled the system, and then downloaded the bitcoin core again. I forgot my wallet, and then the exchange transferred the previous wallet address. Can I still retrieve it?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to recover your coins unless you have a backup of the `wallet.dat` file. If you had a notable amount of coins, you can try using a file recovery software, although I believe they can't recognize wallet files.